# Problem numbering in array sorting even and odd JAVA for looops

Tags: java

I am having a trouble in this numbering when it is arranged in even and odd
My problem is that the 'Arranged Elements'in output number were jumbled.

Source Code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
     Scanner x = new Scanner (System.in);
     System.out.print("Enter the number of elements: ");
     int elements = x.nextInt();

     int a[]= new int[elements];
     for(int y=0;y<a.length;y++)
     {
        System.out.print("Element #"+(y+1)+": ");
        a[y]=x.nextInt();
     }

     System.out.println("");
     System.out.println("Arranged Elements:");

     for(int y=0;y<a.length;y++)
     {
        if(a[y]%2==0)
        {
           System.out.println("Element #"+(y)+": "+a[y]);
        }

     }

     for(int y=0;y<a.length;y++)
     {
         if(a[y]%2!=0)
         {
            System.out.println("Element #"+(y)+": "+a[y]);
         }
     }
     
   }      
}
```

Output:

```
Enter the number of elements: 4

Element #1: 6
Element #2: 5
Element #3: 17
Element #4: 12

Arranged Elements:
Element #0: 6
Element #3: 12
Element #1: 5
Element #2: 17
```

Possilbe Output:

```
Enter the number of elements: 4
Element #1: 6
Element #2: 5
Element #3: 17
Element #4: 12

Arranged Elements:
Element #1: 6
Element #2: 12
Element #3: 5
Element #4: 17
```

Can someone help me out and solve this problem? Thank you!

Comment: What means "possible output" ?

Comment: better change it to "my output" and "expected output".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fix the element numbering in your code, you just add an extra variable to keep track of it, see `elementNumber` variable in the code below and how it is used.

```
System.out.println("");
System.out.println("Arranged Elements:");

// Store the number of the elements printed so far is this variable
int elementNumber=0;
for(int y=0;y<a.length;y++)
{
  if(a[y]%2==0)
  {
    elementNumber++
    System.out.println("Element #"+(elementNumber)+": "+a[y]);
  }
}


for(int y=0;y<a.length;y++)
{
  if(a[y]%2!=0) 
  {
    elementNumber++
    System.out.println("Element #"+(elementNumber)+": "+a[y]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an external `int` that holds the index, also for nicer code you can use `for-each` loops

```
int idx = 0;
for (int val : a) {
    if (val % 2 == 0) {
        System.out.println("Element #" + (++idx) + ": " + val);
    }
}
for (int val : a) {
    if (val % 2 != 0) {
        System.out.println("Element #" + (++idx) + ": " + val);
    }
}
```